# Django: How to mangle through relations

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have an instance of ModelA and want to query all instances of ModelC which are related to ModelA through ModelB.

ModelA -> all ModelB instances with FK rel_a = ModelA -> rel_c.all()

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # fields
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    rel_a = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', ...)
    rel_c = models.ManyToMany('ModelC')
    # more fields

class ModelC(models.Model):
    # fields
    pass
```

I know how I would do this in SQL but I really do not get how I should unmangle these relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query with a [**`.filter(…)`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

```
ModelC.objects.filter(modelb__rel_a=instance_of_modela)
```

You can, like [@IainShelvington says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551319/django-how-to-mangle-through-relations/63551339#comment112377414_63551339), use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to filter out duplicates:

```
ModelC.objects.filter(modelb__rel_a=instance_of_modela).distinct()
```

If you specified a [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) or a [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) in the `ManyToManyField` from `ModelB` to `ModelC` (so `rel_c`), then the name of `modelb` is replaced with that, so then it is:

```
ModelC.objects.filter(related_relc__rel_a=instance_of_modela).distinct()
```

with *`related_relc`* the `related_query_name` or `related_name` in the `rel_c` field.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this may return duplicates and `distinct()` can be used to get unique results